# How to show color images on TcxDBImageComboBox, when Enabled = False

Tags: image, delphi, devexpress

I need to disable **TcxDBImageComboBox** editor, but it shows gray scale images. 
How can I set **Enabled := False;** and show color images?

Comment: I don't use the DevExpress components, but I would guess that unless there is an obvious option to do this then there probably is no way to do this.  If you paid for the source code you might be able to modify the component but that's probably your only hope.

Comment: Check this [question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q327080) in the DevExpress forums. It is about a similar problem and points to a possible solution in one of the comments.